# abntex2 erro de compilação

Tags: latex, abntex2, bibtex

Estou rodando o abntex2 para composição de um trabalho de final de graduação.

Sigo o modelo canônico distribuído pelo abntex2 [aqui](https://code.google.com/p/abntex2/downloads/detail?name=abntex2-modelos-1.9.zip) com algumas modificações para produção do meu trabalho.

A principal modificação é a separação do modelo em vários arquivos menores.
Ao compilar meu documento, recebo a seguinte interrupção de fluxo, solicitando um 'enter', que não sei interpretar:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `boslaugh2008' on page 13 undefined on input line 128.

[13]) [14] [15


] [16] [17

] [18] (./main.bbl (./main.brf)
\tf@brf=\write5
\openout5 = `main.brf'.


bibitemlist
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.
<to be read again> 
                   E
l.49 
     
? 
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.
<to be read again> 
                   E
l.49 
     
? 
[19

])
No file main.ind.
```

Sei que a primeira linha se refere uma uma referência inclusa e ainda não indexada pelo bibtex (isso já foi resolvido). Minha questão se refere a esse trecho:

```
bibitemlist
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.
<to be read again> 
                   E
l.49
```

Imagino que tenha alguma coisa a ver com o hyperref dentro do bibtex, mas não consigo desvendar exatamente o que é, já que tenho múltiplos arquivos e não sei em qual está essa linha 49 apresentada. Além do que, mudanças no arquivo modificam o valor dessa linha, que já foi 81, por exemplo.

## Pergunta

O que pode causar esse erro, e como corrigir?

---

## Actualização:

Consegui isolar o problema, que aparece em duas linhas de `import`, específicas do abntex2cite:

```latex
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}     % Paginas com as citações na bibl
\usepackage[num]{abntex2cite}                    % Citações padrão ABNT

% ---
% Configurações do pacote backref
% Usado sem a opção hyperpageref de backref
\renewcommand{\backrefpagesname}{Citado na(s) página(s):~}
% Texto padrão antes do número das páginas
\renewcommand{\backref}{}
% Define os textos da citação
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
    \ifcase #1 %
        Nenhuma citação no texto.%
    \or
        Citado na página #2.%
    \else
        Citado #1 vezes nas páginas #2.%
    \fi}%
```

Entendo que o "isolar" aqui não seja muito específico, mas se comentarmos as duas linhas de `\usepackage` acima, o problema para de aparecer.

Coloquei o código que segue aqueles dois `\usepackage` por entender que podem ser relevantes ao problema.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54291/discussion-on-question-by-luizangioletti-abntex2-erro-de-compilacao)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você já verificou se alguma das suas URLs (incluindo as das suas referências bibliográficas) possui um caracter especial do LaTeX? Parece com um erro antigo quando URLs contém `#`, por exemplo.

Eu procuraria no seu arquivo de referências do BibTeX por urls que contenham #. Se for o caso, é só trocá-las por `\#`.

Se você tem poucas referências usadas no texto, também poderia comentar cada ocorrência para descobrir qual é a problemática.

Dá para ter uma pista de onde está essa referência vendo que o erro aparece entre

> [18]  (./main.bbl (./main.brf)

e

> [19]

Ou seja está depois que a 18ª página foi gerada e antes da 19ª, então provavelmente é uma das referências que aparecem na 19ª página gerada. Como você só consegue gerar o seu texto quando comenta as inclusões de pacotes relativos a citações, é possível que talvez você tenha que olhar também algumas páginas antes ou depois da 19ª quando rodar a versão comentada. Digo 19ª página porque isso não necessariamente é a página de número 19. Depende de você usar numeração romana para a parte pré-textual e outras coisas.

Um exemplo de alguém que passou por mensagem de erro similar (em inglês):

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-docs/200306.mbox/%3CPine.WNT.4.55.0306130932240.1420@Poste3947.hec.ca%3E

Comment: Fiz duas coisas, seguindo sua sugestão: encontrei dois `#` dentro de URLs, os quais escapei com `\#`. Depois disso, comentei uma por uma das minhas 23 citações, e o erro permanece. Pensando que o erro poderia estar acontecendo em mais de um lugar ao mesmo tempo (apesar da única mensagem de erro) comentei metade do arquivo alternadamente. O erro permanece.

Comment: O erro permanece até que se execute `bibtex arquivo` para que o sistema atualize as referências que serão utilizadas na composição do documento. Você está correto, Ailton! Resposta aceita!